# Having problems passing values and outputting them using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here's the page: bit.ly/m5cyjx

What I'm trying to do is to pass the value of the select element (i.e. EUR, USD, etc.), as well as the value of the left text input (i.e. 100) to the form on the bottom of the page.

When I submit the form, I can see that it is only passing the default values of the text input and the select element. Namely, it passes the values that each element contains upon page load rather than the ones I input.

The form is submitted using jQuery $.post.

Furthermore, I'm trying to dynamically show the resultant value in the right text area. I believe the PHP is working properly, but here it is anyway:

```
<?php
//convert to selected currency from BTC
$currencySelectValue = $_POST['currencySelectValue'];
$currencyValue = $_POST['currencyValue'];
$lastPrice = $_POST['lastPrice'];

if($currencySelectValue == "USD")
{
    $convertedResult = ($currencyValue / $lastPrice);
}
else
{
    //convert currency to USD
    $convertJSON = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=" . $currencyValue . $currencySelectValue . "%3D%3FUSD", true);
    $convertArr = json_decode($tickerJSON, true);
    $currencyValue = $convertArr["rhs"];
    $currencyValue = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $currencyValue);
    $convertedResult = ($currencyValue / $lastPrice);
}

echo $convertedResult;
?>
```

jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fromCurrencyValue').inlineFieldLabel({
            label: 'Currency Value'
        });
        $('#btcValue').inlineFieldLabel({
            label: 'BTC Value'
        });
        $('#currencySelect').selectmenu({
            style: 'popup',
            width: 100
        });
        $('#convertToButton').button();
        $('#convertFromButton').button();
        $('#convertToButton').click(function() {
            $.post("php/convertToForm.php", $("#convertToForm").serialize(), function(data){ 
                $('#toCurrencyValue').val(data);
            });
        });
        $('#convertFromButton').click(function() {
            $.post("php/convertFromForm.php", $("#convertFromForm").serialize(), function(data){ 
                $('#fromCurrencyValue').val(data);
            });
        });


        $("#currencySelectValue").val($("#currencySelect").val());
        $("#currencyValue").val($("#fromCurrencyValue").val());
        $("#btcValueForm").val($("#btcValue").val());
    });
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to show your JQuery code so we know what's wrong with the POST.

Comment: You should have a look at my comment on your previous post. The regular expression you're using in preg_replace won't work for amount that have a decimal point which most currency conversion will have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what your problem is. Looking at the data that's being passed to the PHP script, the value of "currencyValue" is passed as "Currency Value". In your script, you have `$currencyValue = $_POST['currencyValue'];` and then `$currencyValue / $lastPrice`.

The problem is that $currencyValue is text and not a number. The division of "Currency Value" / 19.8 is invalid.

**EDIT:** The value of "currencyValue" is set in your jQuery code when it does this: `$("#currencyValue").val($("#fromCurrencyValue").val());`. That calls happens as soon as the page loads. This is probably not what you want. Instead, you should move that to your onclick event handlers.

Comment: I see you've made some progress. The data is now being passed properly... but it's not add the data in the right field when the $.post finishes because $('#toCurrentValue') doesn't exist.  The field seems to be called $('#btcValue')...

Comment: Converting the other way doesn't work because the "currencySelectValue" is empty when it's sent. You have 2 elements with ID "currencySelectValue" and jQuery is only setting the first one (which is "convert to"). You should rename the second one to something different as ID attributes should be unique.